# Multiple Domain and Multi Directory in the same Django App

Tags: python, django, multiple-domains

I am trying to support a quite complex architecture with mixed multiple domains and multiple directory in the same django application. Basically, we'll have urls like this :

```
http://www.firstdomains.com/(DJANGO_APP)
http://www.firstdomains.com/de/(DJANGO_APP)
http://www.other.com/esp/best/(DJANGO_APP)
http://www.complex.com/it/(DJANGO_APP)
http://www.last.com/(DJANGO_APP)
.... (lot more)
```

The "combo" domain/directory will determine a theme website and a language. What do you think is the best way to implement this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in luck!  [Carl Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3207/carl-meyer) recently released the perfect app for you: [django-hosts](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-hosts)

If for some reason the URL parts don't work for you try also adding one of the apps that do URL i18n/l10n such as http://pypi.python.org/pypi/transurlvania